# Is the inverse of the following function correct

Tags: functions

Function is

> Q(x) = 1/2 + 1/2*[erf(x/sqrt(2)]

Inverse calculate is

> Q_inverse(x) = sqrt(2)erfinv(2x-1)

Comment: Sorry to ask....I rechecked it on Matlab and it is the same. I was having continuous error due to missing one single parameter in coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rechecked it multiple times and the Inverse I have mentioned is all ok. I feel necessary to post the correct answer.